# Flutter Stuck In Loop When Setting Object Value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following object:

```
class MyObject {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  double? quantity;
  double? unit_value;


  MyObject({ 
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    this.quantity,
    this.unit_value,
  });
}
```

I'm trying to loop through a list of these objects while updating the values.

```
  Future<List<MyObject>> getData() async {

    // Pull current objects from db
    List<MyObject> myobjects = await DatabaseHandler().listObjects();


    for (var i = 0; i < myobjects.length; i++) {
        var current_object = myobjects[i];
        print(1);
        var current_unit_value = _dataMap[current_object.id]['price'];
        print(current_unit_value);
        current_object.unit_value = current_unit_value;
        print(2);

        // Update db
        DatabaseHandler().updateObject(current_object);
    }

    // Pull db
    myobjects = await DatabaseHandler().listObjects();

    return myobjects;

  }
```

However the loop gets stuck at `current_object.unit_value = current_unit_value;`

This is the output

```
flutter: 1
flutter: 45
```

It never gets to the second print statement and there are no errors returned. If I comment out that line everything runs perfectly and I get the list back but the field isn’t updated.

All suggestions/input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this is your code?  Are you sure that `MyObject` doesn't have a `unit_value` setter that accidentally calls itself recursively?  If not, can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: @jamesdlin It is my code and there is no explicit setter for `unit_value`. 

What else would be helpful for you to see?

Comment: From the code you've shown, the behavior you described should not be possible.  Distilling your code into a minimal, self-contained example that can reproduce the problem would help.  The process of doing so might give you insight into the cause too.